# Remote control is disabled after reboot

Tags: remote, openelec

Every time I reboot my rapsberry 2 with OpenELEC the [remote control](http://www.htpcbeginner.com/simple-cheap-raspberry-pi-remote-control/) is not working until I unplug it and plug again.

Is there any way to solve this problem?